# apostrophe_regex

Tags: ios, regex, swift4

How to `allow` user to enter only `numbers`, `characters`, `whitespaces` and `apostrophes`. do anyone have idea about this?
I have tried the following regex but it does not work.
[\sa-zA-Z0-9\']

I want to allow all characters don't want to make any restriction to type character but the end of the textfieldDidEndEditing, I want to validate the string in above scenario.

Comment: Try `^[A-Za-z0-9' ]+$` https://regex101.com/r/6pimSb/1

Comment: @S.Kablar it gives me error. it let me not allow the apostrophe

Comment: try this [\\sa-zA-Z0-9']*